# C# Replacing an Object in a class of Objects dynamically ~

Tags: c#, object, types, casting, type-conversion

I guess this is my 2nd post kinda on the same topic, kinda...

Anyway, I would like to update my agents *AIbundles* class dynamically by passing an AI behavior to replace or add:

**Not Working code*

```
public class agent
{
    AIbundles = new AIbundle();

    public void UpdateBehavior (object Behavior)
    {
        object CastedBehavior = (Behavior.type) Behavior; //Cast
        this.agent.AIbundles.(Behavior.type) = CastedBehavior; 
    }
}
```

Example of my AIbundles class (extremely simplified)

```
public class AIbundles 
{
    ExampleBehavior1 ExampleBehavior1;
    ExampleBehavior2 ExampleBehavior2;
    ExampleBehavior3 ExampleBehavior3;

    AIbundles()
    {
        ExampleBehavior1 = new ExampleBehavior1();
        ExampleBehavior2 = new ExampleBehavior2();
        ExampleBehavior3 = new ExampleBehavior3();
    }
}
```

Sadly I am quite aware that this is a very bad way of implementing this, is there a better way of handling objects dynamically?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: You might be interested in the strategy pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: In short i'm trying to make a method that will do *X* with any Object it can do *X* with~

Comment: So you have different behavior implementations and want one agent to handle all the different behaviors right?

Comment: @Ela Pretty much, i want to have one method take a number of different kinds of objects~ I know how to do this, just not a *GOOD* way to do it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your `ExampleBehavior` classes should extend some base type (whether it's an abstract class or an interface depends on your situation). Let's call the base type `BehaviorBase`. Then your `AIBundle` class should have a property of type `BehaviorBase` called `Behavior`, and you can do something like this, without any sort of casting:

```
public void UpdateBehavior(BehaviorBase behavior) {
   this.agent.AIbundles.Behavior = behavior;
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
var agent = ...;
var someAIThing = initWithAgent(agent);
BehaviorBase behavior = ...;
someAIThing.UpdateBehavior(behavior);
```

At this point, I would strongly consider eliminating the `UpdateBehavior` method and simply assign the behavior to the property directly:

```
var agent = ...;
var someAIThing = initWithAgent(agent);
BehaviorBase behavior = ...;
agent.AIBundles.Behavior = behavior;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not create a property of each type within your "collection" like class.
Instead use a Dictionary if you want to retrieve the right behavior by name.
Or simply a List of behaviors.
Each behavior could have something like a name or type property, to identify it, if needed.
You could also just have a IBehavior interface which has methods which are common...

something like this might do it for you I think:

```
    public class AIbundles
    {
        public Dictionary<string, IExampleBehavior> ExampleBehaviors { get; set; }

        public AIbundles()
        {
            this.ExampleBehaviors = new Dictionary<string, IExampleBehavior>();
        }

    } 

    public class agent {
        AIbundles bundles = new AIbundles();

        public void UpdateBehavior (IExampleBehavior behavior)
        {
            this.bundles.ExampleBehaviors[behavior.Name] = behavior;
        }
     }
```